# Python Split String On Newline And Keep Newline

Tags: python, split, newline, delimiter

Is there a way to split a string containing a newline character into a list of strings where the newline character has been retained, eg.

```
"amount\nexceeds"
```

would produce

```
["amount\n", "exceeds"]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines), passing `keepends=True`:

```
"amount\nexceeds".splitlines(keepends=True)
```

gives you:

```
["amount\n", "exceeds"]
```